# Global existence of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I see whether or not these ODE's have a global solution:

$$x'=t^2+x^2$$

$$x'=t^2+x$$

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the weaker form of the Cauchy theorem (probably known to many as Picard–Lindelöf theorem) to $$x'=f(t,x),$$ $\partial f/\partial x$ is required to be bounded (this implies it is Lipschitz with respect to $x$, for any $t$), and this is true for the second equation where such derivatives gives $1$, but not for the first, where it gives $2x$.

Answer (score -5):

Here is a paper relating to this matter: [Ref.](http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~elias/2008-JMAA-global.pdf)