# Qualitative study of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Cauchy problem
$$u'(t)=3t-e^{-u(t)^2}$$
$$u(0)=0$$
with $t≥0$.
I want to study the existence of a global solution.
I want to use the global existence theorem.
I have, using the triangular inequality
$$|3t-e^{-u(t)^2}|≤3t+e^{-u(t)^2}$$
Furthermore
$$\forall t≥0 e^{-u(t)^2}≤u+1$$
And then
$$|3t-e^{-u(t)^2}|≤3t+e^{-u(t)^2}≤3t+1+u(t)≤3t+1+|u(t)|$$
Then the solution is global for the global existence theorem. I am novice with this kind of problems. Is my solution correct?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176469/global-existence-of-solutions may be useful.

Comment: can't you integrate  $3t-1 < u' < 3t$ to get $1.5t^2 - t < u < 1.5t^2?$

Answer (score 1):

Use argument by contradiction. Suppose there is $t_0>0$ such that
$$ \lim_{t\to t_0^-}|u(t)|=\infty. \tag{1}$$
Note
\begin{eqnarray}
|u(t)|&=&\left|\int_0^tu'(s)ds\right|=\left|\int_0^t(3s-e^{-u(t)^2})ds\right|\\
&=&\left|\frac32t^2-\int_0^te^{-u(s)^2}ds\right|\\
&\le&\frac32t^2+\int_0^te^{-u(s)^2}ds\\
&=&\frac32t^2+\int_0^tds\\
&=&\frac32t^2+t
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \limsup_{t\to t_0^-}|u(t)|\le \frac32t_0^2+t_0<\infty$$
which is against (1).